# How to exclude a charachter in sublime text regex match and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have the following for which I am trying to use the ST regex replace:

```
echo Street = $this->input->post('Street');
echo City= $this->input->post('City');
```

I want to turn each line into:

```
echo City= trim($this->input->post('City'));
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
\$this(.+);
```

but this matches the entire line including the final ';'

how can I select only:

```
$this->input->post('City')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\$this([^;]+)
```

`[^;]` means anything but semicolon :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want

```
\$this([^;]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

`=\s\$this(.+\')`
Should work. I am not certain about sublime texts RE engine specifics.